# Multi Wait handle

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have code such as:

```
public void MethodA()
{
    MyManualResetEvent.Reset();
}

public void MethodB()
{
    MyManualResetEvent.Set();
}
```

This works when using `MyManualResetEvent.WaitOne()` to stop a thread if another thread has called `MethodA` but not `MethodB`.

What i want to do now is be able to call `MethodA` twice, with another thread only continuing if `MethodB` is called twice, rather than just once.

I'm hoping there's something in the [System.Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx) namespace i don't know about.

Comment: Use two events and WaitMultiple perhaps?

Comment: 2 is just an example, i want it to work for the general case. i.e. any number of call pairs. That might be an idea though, could i use a list of reset events or something? Not sure if this would cause issues or be awkward to maintain.

Comment: A good overview of .Net threading resources http://www.albahari.com/threading/threading.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to stop a concurrently-executing `BlockedMethod` the instant `MethodA` is called, this is probably most easily solved with the standard [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) class. `MethodA` and `MethodB` share a counter which records how many times `MethodA` has been called without a corresponding call to `MethodB`. The `BlockedMethod` method only proceeds if that count is 0; if not, it waits for `MethodB` to signal it that it's time to proceed.

```
object mylock = new object();
int count = 0;

public void MethodA()
{
    // record that MethodA is executing
    lock (mylock)
        count++;

    // other code...
}

public void MethodB()
{
    // other code...

    lock (mylock)
    {
        // MethodB has now finished running
        count--;

        // wake up other thread because it may now be allowed to run
        Monitor.Pulse(mylock);
    }
}

public void BlockedMethod()
{
    // wait until the number of calls to A and B is equal (i.e., count is 0)
    lock (mylock)
    {
        while (count != 0)
             Monitor.Wait(mylock);
    }

    // calls to A and B are balanced, proceed...
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work since the `BlockedMethod` thread could be waiting, holding `MyLock`, which prevents the `MethodB` thread from d-incrementing count, or have i misunderstood?

Comment: @George, `Monitor.Wait` will release the lock on `mylock` and then block until `Pulse` is called to wake it up (by `MethodB`). Or, if count==0, it will exit the while loop immediately, release the lock and proceed with its work. See the documentation on Monitor.Wait: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateab679.aspx

Comment: Ahh, ok, didn't realise `Monitor.Wait` would release it too. I think i need to brush up on my threading concepts!

Comment: Accepted this answer because in my view it's the simplest one (even i can understand it!).

Answer (score 4):

`CountdownEvent` may be what you are looking for.

From MSDN: "Represents a synchronization primitive that is signaled when its count reaches zero."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx
It's only available in .NET 4.

Comment: I've taken a look at this, and have read http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/aa49f92c-01a8-4901-9846-91bc1587f3ae but i can't seem to work out how to get it working in my case as i'm not sure how to get my waiting thread to carry on if the current count is 1 not zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `System.Threading.Semaphore` to do such things.

In a simple version this could look like:

```
    System.Threading.Semaphore s1 = new System.Threading.Semaphore(2, 2);

    public void BeginSomething()
    {
        // This decrements the value of s1.
        s1.WaitOne();
    }

    public void EndSomething()
    {
        // This increments the value of s1.
        s1.Release();
    }

    public void BlockedMethod()
    {
        bool execute = true;
        // Try to get access.
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            if (!s1.WaitOne(0))
            {
                for (; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    s1.Release();
                }
                execute = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (execute)
        {
            // This code is only executed if s1 has its starting value 2.

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                s1.Release();
            }
        }
    }
```

But i think using this way you would still need one semaphore to control the balace of a function pair.

Comment: I've looked at a semaphore, but it looks like that allows multiple (configurable number of) threads access to something (a resource or code-block for example), causing any more to wait. I'm not sure i can use it in my case. If i can an example would be great.

Comment: Sorry, i still don't understand how to use this with a varying number of paris of calls.